# Drop column if exists in SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to drop the column if it is already exists in the table else not throw any error.

Tried:

```
ALTER TABLE Emp 
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS Lname;
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

By searching I came to know that, this option is available from 2016.

What is the alternative in the SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: 'DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS' it's mysql, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @StanislavKundii SQL Server 2016+ supports that syntax as well.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'Emp'
                      AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Lname'
                      AND TABLE_SCHEMA='DBO')
  BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE Emp
        DROP COLUMN Lname
  END
GO
```

Comment: how we will tweak above statement if one has to drop multiple columns? Please suggest

Comment: @vikrant rana you'll have to wrap each column you need to drop in separate if statements

Comment: @Paul O... Thanks. I will give it a try soon.

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN social [documentation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/27e249b8-e7ec-4714-a3c3-e5c5e6e88f29/drop-columns-if-they-exists-in-table?forum=transactsql), we can try:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects o
          INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
          WHERE o.name = 'Emp' AND c.name = 'Lname')
ALTER TABLE dbo.Emp DROP COLUMN Lname;
```

Comment: Oh... Why join? 'c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Emp')' and Top?

Answer (score 3):

I followed this way.

```
IF COL_LENGTH (N'{Your_TableName}', N'{Your_ColumnName}') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE {Your_TableName}
    DROP COLUMN {Your_ColumnName};`
END 
GO
```